# RabbitMQ 3.6.5 crashes with high memory utilization

Tags: rabbitmq

Our cluster is comprised of 3 disc nodes in HA. All nodes are 4CPUx26Gig RAM. We use RabbitMQ 3.6.5, with Erlang 17.3.
The only plugin enabled is the management UI plugin.

The problem is that in the span of 3 hours usually, one of the servers (usually the one with most queues on) would start to gradually hog memory, until the server crashes.
This happens daily and we don't see any reason for that to happen in the logs.

Attached are the logs for the server from when it piled up with 21GB of memory, at which point, when looking at the overview pane in the management UI - it shows only 2GB is being utilized. When this happens, we usually have ~400 connections, with ~470 channels, 16 exchanges, 54 queues, and ~300 consumers.
One of the queues is TTL enabled, 4 are priority queues, and all of the queues are durable.

Upon service restart, everything goes back to normal.

Any ideas as to what's causing it / How should we approach debugging ? A checklist of known issues to rule out ?

```
Status of node 'rabbit@scraped-node-name' ...
[{pid,399},
 {running_applications,
     [{rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","3.6.5"},
      {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,"RabbitMQ Web Dispatcher","3.6.5"},
      {webmachine,"webmachine","1.10.3"},
      {mochiweb,"MochiMedia Web Server","2.13.1"},
      {rabbitmq_management_agent,"RabbitMQ Management Agent","3.6.5"},
      {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.6.5"},
      {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.3"},
      {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.6.5"},
      {rabbit_common,[],"3.6.5"},
      {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.12.3"},
      {ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","5.3.6"},
      {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","0.22.1"},
      {crypto,"CRYPTO","3.4.1"},
      {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","5.10.3"},
      {compiler,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","5.0.2"},
      {xmerl,"XML parser","1.3.7"},
      {syntax_tools,"Syntax tools","1.6.16"},
      {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 3.0.2","3.0.2"},
      {ranch,"Socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols.","1.2.1"},
      {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.4.1"},
      {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.2"},
      {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","3.0.3"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,
     "Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:64] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,
     [{total,2049513496},
      {connection_readers,10231416},
      {connection_writers,3215768},
      {connection_channels,35753016},
      {connection_other,14065960},
      {queue_procs,430585272},
      {queue_slave_procs,34912},
      {plugins,525312},
      {other_proc,33015816},
      {mnesia,333080},
      {mgmt_db,33680},
      {msg_index,38121640},
      {other_ets,6595504},
      {binary,1432921304},
      {code,27606184},
      {atom,992409},
      {other_system,15482223}]},
 {alarms,[]},
 {listeners,[{clustering,25672,"::"},{amqp,5672,"::"}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,10983032422},
 {disk_free_limit,50000000},
 {disk_free,148079415296},
 {file_descriptors,
     [{total_limit,32668},
      {total_used,440},
      {sockets_limit,29399},
      {sockets_used,418}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,4683}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,117601},
 {kernel,{net_ticktime,60}}]
```

Comment: Could you post  all logs?

Comment: And which OS are you using ? ( Centos ?)

Comment: Without log, it's impossible to help you, please post all information asked.